# How do I unlock courses in Mario Kart Wii?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I imagine I have to win some cups in single-player mode.  Can someone be more specific than that?  A link to a site with the info would be fine.  I'm disappointed by the organization of the sites I checked out.  I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, you just need to get a medal (bronze, silver or gold) in single player Grand Prix mode in each cup.

> **Star Cup** => Finish 3rd or better in Mushroom Cup and Flower Cup
>   **Special Cup** => Finish 3rd or better in Star Cup (which means that you
>   also finished 3rd or better in Mushroom Cup and Flower Cup)
>
> **Leaf Cup** => Finish 3rd or better in Shell Cup and Banana Cup
>   **Lightning Cup** => Finish 3rd or better in Leaf Cup (which means that you also
>   finished 3rd or better in Shell Cup and Banana Cup)

Answer (score 0):

You have to beat all the different cups on the different classes (50cc, 100cc, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

star cup: get third place or better in the mushroom cup and flower cup in either 50c,100c, or 150c

special cup: get third or better in the star cup in either 50c,100c, or 150c

leaf cup: get third place or better in the shell cup and the banana cup in either 50c,100c, or 150c

lightning cup: get third place or better in leaf cup in either 50c,100c, or 150c

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been said, I'm afraid.